# Default route for Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I'm using Apache Camel. Using XML DSL, I mean something like

```
<rests id="rests" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <rest id="rest-custom">
        <get uri="my_method" method="">
            <description>...</description>
            <param name="..." ... />
            <route>
                <process ref="..." />
                <to uri="..." />
            </route>
        </get>

        <post uri="another_method" method="" >
            <description>...</description>
            <param name="..." .../>
            <route>
                <process ref="..." />
                <to uri="..." />
            </route>
        </post>
...
```

So if I want new route, I will just add new `<get>` or `<post>` and it works fine.

But now I want to add some **DEFAULT** method. I mean, something like `<get uri="*">` and `<post uri="*">` in the bottom of all configuration. So if my url doesn't match any from list - it goes to default one and I can handle it with custom processor (this is the behaviour I want).

For now I don't know, how to do it. Tried to handle 404 responses, but still no success. Looks like solution should be simple, but can't find it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

```
<get uri="/?matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;bridgeEndpoint=true" method="">
    <description>Default GET method</description>
    <route>
       ...
    </route>
</get>
```

Parameters **matchOnUriPrefix=true&bridgeEndpoint=true** did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I see only one possible use case for such a default: if you got **multiple URLs for the same functionality**.

If this is the case and your clients don't want or can't switch to a single URL, you could still use **URL rewriting** on the incoming request before it reaches your Camel application.

If you want to **"catch" all unknown URLs** (errors), I guess you should use **standard Camel error handling** (see [Error Handler](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/error-handler.html) and [Exception clause](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html)) because these REST DSL blocks are internally converted to standard Camel routes.